# Replacement Hoods for SRAM Rival 1 Levers

Tags: parts, sram, shopping

I have a [2020 Kona Rove ST](https://99spokes.com/bikes/kona/2020/rove-st) with [SRAM Rival 1](https://www.sram.com/en/sram/road/series/sram-rival-1) shifters/levers/a brifter. It's a 1x11 speed. My local bike shop recently did some work on my bike, and it seems they tore my hood. It was definitely not like this when the bike went in.

[image: photo of a ripped SRAM Rival 1 lever hood]

I'd like to buy replacement hoods. I'm having a difficult time determining which hoods that I've found online are compatible and will work best with my levers. When I've Googled and looked at various distributor websites I typically would see three or so types of [SRAM hoods like in this example result from Jenson](https://www.jensonusa.com/Hoods-Parts-Accessories?brand=SRAM)

**[SRAM Doubletap Lever Hoods 10 Speed](https://www.jensonusa.com/SRAM-Doubletap-Lever-Hoods)**

> Fits SRAM drop bar brakes and 10-speed DoubleTap Shift levers (with the exception of the redesigned 2013 SRAM Red)

These *seem like* they should be compatible. My brifter lever *does* say "DoubleTap" on it, but no-one in the reviews/Q&A mentions Rival 1 so I'm hesitant. It's also unfortunate that the hoods do not appear to be textured, and are a bit of a downgrade from my current hoods.

**[SRAM 22 Brake Hood Covers Textured](https://www.jensonusa.com/SRAM-22-Brake-Hood-Covers-Textured)**

> Designed to work with 2012 Red, Red 22, Force 22, and Rival 22 Levers

This sounds promising since it mentions `Rival`, but it's `Rival 22`, which seems distinct from the `Rival 1`. Both rival models are listed under the [Rival 1 family on SRAM's website](https://www.sram.com/en/sram/road/series/sram-rival-1) so maybe they're compatible?

**[SRAM AXS eTap Hoods for Cable Brake Levers](https://www.jensonusa.com/SRAM-AXS-eTap-Hoods-for-Cable-Brake-Levers)**

> Only compatible with AXS eTap Cable Brake Levers

Seems like I can rule this one out since AXS is a distinct/separate family from Rival and these are clearly only for AXS

I am wondering if there are better methodologies for finding replacement hoods and/or if there is a definitive answer to what SRAM hoods currently on sale would be compatible with Rival 1 levers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's the second option, the "SRAM Cable Brake Hood Covers, Black, Fit 2013 Red 10-Speed, Red 22, Force 22, Rival 22, Pair". SRAM part number for black is 00.7918.010.000. To my awareness the Rival 1 right control is literally the same part as the Rival 22 one, and the Rival 1 left uses the same hood as a Rival 22 left. SRAM did a terrible job of publicizing how this works.

Answer (score 2):

Nathan's answer seems to be correct, but I wanted to provide additional context to anyone searching for this issue in the future. See here a photo of one of my stock hoods that was installed when I originally purchased my bike from a local bike shop

[image: top-down photograph of the left brake hood of a Kona Rove 2020 ST bicycle]

See here a photo of one of the new hoods (00.7918.010.000) after it was installed at a local bike shop.

[image: top-down photograph of the left brake hood of a Kona Rove 2020 ST bicycle] [image: photograph of the back of a box for SRAM Rival hoods part number 00.7918.010.000]

These replacement hoods do appear to be the correct choice. The lighting between the two photos is slightly different, but overall the hoods appear identical from the outside. However, I've found the new hoods do not seem to fit the same as the original hoods.

The [bumps/protrusions/internal bosses and hooks](https://youtu.be/Ty0Q9sof0ew) used to align the hood with the brake lever don't "feel" right. Despite having a local bike shop try their best (a different LBS than the one that originally tore my hoods), and my own efforts to massage and align the hoods into place, they do not feel the same as the original stock hoods. The top-down photos of the hoods show a bump/protrusion that was not present originally. I can feel bumps that did not used to be present, and the hood does not make an ideal seal where it wraps around the lever.

Again, I think Nathan's answer is correct, but I also think the hoods are either very tricky to get "just right" or that maybe these replacement hoods are perhaps slightly different from what I originally had.

Comment: The photo of the new hood seems to show it's twisted a bit - the seam on the top isn't straight.  Maybe some twisting the hood a bit to straighten that seam might help seat it better?  FWIW, when I replaced some Shimano 105 hoods after a crash, they had the same can't-get-them "just right" feel to them.  Either they "got better" or I just got used to them.

Comment: At times I've squirted rubbing alcohol all over the inside, then put one nub in place, then coerced the next into place etc. The alcohol lubricates then dries clean.